# Creating columns from combination of others in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| Product | Version | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.2.3 | X |
| A | 1.2.3 | Y |
| A | 1.2.4 | X |
| A | 1.2.4 | Z |
| A | 1.2.5 | X |
| A | 1.2.5 | Y |
| A | 1.2.5 | Z |
| A | 1.3.0 | X |
| A | 1.3.0 | Y |
| A | 1.3.1 | X |
| A | 1.3.2 | Y |
| A | 1.3.2 | X |
| A | 1.3.2 | Z |

I need a table which contains, for each product, how many times a version has been deployed on (X and Y and Z), (X and Y but not Z), (X and Z but not X), (X but not Y and not Z) and the total.

**Note**:

- There is more than X, Y, Z target, but I'm interested only by those ones.
- A version can be deployed multiple times in same target

Something like:

| Product | X_Y_Z | X_Y | X_Z | X_only | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 6 |

I find the [Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) function, which allows me to have columns by individual environment grouped by configuration of deployments, with following query:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    COUNT(Version) AS Versions,
    IIF(X > 0, 1, 0) AS X,
    IIF(Y > 0, 1, 0) AS Y,
    IIF(Z > 0, 1, 0) AS Z
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ID,
         Product,
         Version,
         Target
     FROM 
         Delivery
     GROUP BY 
         ID, Product, Version, Target) AS src
PIVOT
    (COUNT(ID) FOR Target IN (X, Y, Z)) AS pivotTable
WHERE 
    X > 0
GROUP BY
    PROJ_LABEL,
    IIF(X > 0, 1, 0) AS X,
    IIF(Y > 0, 1, 0) AS Y,
    IIF(Z > 0, 1, 0) AS Z;
```

Which give me:

| Product | Versions | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

But I don't find how to reach my final goal.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like you might be able to use your current query as a sub-query, and with a CASE expression, get the output you're seeking.

Comment: I do have one question: in the table of the results you want to get, you show 3 for 'X_Y', but looking at your current results, I only see that the top two rows have a 1 for X and Y, leading me to presume it should be 2, not 3. How are you calculating your X_Y_Z, X_Y, X_Z, and X_only rows?

Comment: @jw11432, thanks for your comment. I did not added all values in the example. I edited the post to fix it. By the way, I don't understand how I can use a CASE to gt expected results. Do you have an exemple?

Comment: To be clear, the table you have is like the first table above, and what you want to achieve is the example below "Something like:" with one row and the aggregations, and what you've managed to achieve on your own is in the last table, under "Which give me:". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find a way:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    SUM(X_Y_Z) AS 'X_Y_Z',
    SUM(X_Y) AS 'X_Y',
    SUM(X_Z) AS 'X_Z',
    SUM(X) AS 'X only',
    SUM(X_Y_Z) + SUM(X_Y) + SUM(X_Z) + SUM(X) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT
        Product,
        X_Y_Z*value AS X_Y_Z,
        X_Y*value AS X_Y,
        X_Z*value AS X_Z,
        X*value AS X
    FROM (
        SELECT
            Product,
            COUNT(Version) AS Versions,
            IIF(X > 0, 1, 0) AS X,
            IIF(Y > 0, 1, 0) AS Y,
            IIF(Z > 0, 1, 0) AS Z
        FROM 
            (SELECT
                 ID,
                 Product,
                 Version,
                 Target
             FROM 
                 Delivery
             GROUP BY 
                 ID, Product, Version, Target) AS src
        PIVOT
            (COUNT(ID) FOR Target IN (X, Y, Z)) AS pivotTable
        WHERE 
            X > 0
        GROUP BY
            Product,
            IIF(X > 0, 1, 0) AS X,
            IIF(Y > 0, 1, 0) AS Y,
            IIF(Z > 0, 1, 0) AS Z;
        ) AS tmp
    ) AS tmp2
GROUP BY Product
ORDER BY 1 ASC
;
```

I don't knnow if it's the best way, but it seems to work.